# Platform does not define a GLUT font retrieval function

Tags: python

I am trying to install a cozmo SDK on my ubuntu (v 20.4). I followed the instructions from the http://cozmosdk.anki.com/docs/install-linux.html and at the end I always get the same error. "Platform does not define a GLUT font retrieval function".
I did try installing it on my Host PC however I ended up with the same error message.
[image: error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with the python version. Easy solution: use ubuntu version 20.04.